# How to force Cmake execute a top-level CMakeLists.txt of a multi component dependency?

Tags: android, c, android-studio, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to make my android project with C support. Let's say I have the following structure (everything is source directories, no binaries):

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/main/cpp/|
             |---Executable1/
             |---Executable2/
             |---deps/
```

In this CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(ProjectName)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/assets/${ANDROID_ABI}")
add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/deps)
add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/Executable1)
add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/Executable2)
```

In "deps" folder I have the following structure:

```
deps/|
     |---CMakeLists.txt
     |---Library1/
     |---LIbrary2/
```

In this CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
add_subdirectory(Library1)
add_subdirectory(Library2)
```

And in Library2 I have 2 modules:

```
Library2/|---CMakeLists.txt
         |---Module1/
         |---Module2/
```

In this CMakeLists.txt I have

```
project(Library2)
include_directories ( BEFORE SYSTEM ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Module1
                                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Module2
                                Module1
                                . )
add_subdirectory( Module1 )
add_subdirectory( Module2 )
```

Module1 and Module2 are libraries which I add by

```
add_library(Module1 STATIC sourceM1_1.c sourceM1_2.c ...)
```

and

```
add_library(Module2 STATIC sourceM2_1.c sourceM2_2.c ...)
```

in their CMakeLists.txt respectively.

Executable2 has in its CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(Executable2  sourceE2_1.c sourceE2_2.c ...)
target_link_libraries(Executable2 Module1 Module2)
```

If the things are made in this way, I get errors while Module1 is being compiled.

Errors say that some headers weren't found. These headers are present inside the "Library2" directory.

If I comment out the Executable2 in the topmost CMakeLists.txt, everything compiles fine.

So the question is how to force CMake to execute the instructions inside "Library2/CMakeLists.txt" or what do I have to do to add the needed include directories? I guess I can add them directly to CMakeLists.txt of "Module1" and "Module2" but I think it's not a good practice.

Comment: "I get errors while Module1 is being compiled." ... "If I comment out the Executable2 in the topmost CMakeLists.txt, everything compiles fine." - So you get the errors while compile the **executable** `Executable2`, not while compile the *module* `Module1`, don't you?

Comment: No. The practice showed that if I have some executables, that depend on some libraries, cmake goes through the hierarchy of CMakeLists.txt from top to bottom, extracts only those targets that correspond to the dependencies of the executable, builds them, builds the executable and links the executable to the libraries. That's so if libs are static. If they're shared, they are also included to the APK but the process looks the same. If I have some library targets and nothing depends on them, they are built stanalone according to the CMakeLists hierarchy and included to APK if they're shared.

Comment: I am not expert in Android, but from CMake's point of view the things differs from ones you describe. Plesase, update your question with **exact error message**, which includes the name of the object file which is built.

Comment: Well, actually I have found a workaround myself already and can't reproduce the exact same error. I can only say that Library2 is OpenSSL with CMake build system from [https://github.com/pol51/OpenSSL-CMake](https://github.com/pol51/OpenSSL-CMake)
and the problem was while building crypto library and it said that in header e_os.h on line 64 it couldn't refer to <openssl/e_os2.h>

Comment: In **build.gradle** you can specify [targets](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions:targets) to override the natural CMake preference to build the executables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some time I found a workaround myself. I couldn't get Cmake to not ignore the Library2 CMakeLists.txt, so I just added the missing include_directory refering to Library2 to Module1 and Module2 CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: that means, that in **Module1/CMakeLists.txt** you now say `include_directories ( BEFORE SYSTEM ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR))` and same for **Module2** ?

Comment: That means I added  `BEFORE SYSTEM ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/Library2)` to `include_directories`. As I said in my last comment under the question, I had a problem with OpenSSL and its Crypto and LibSSL modules. I also had some other issues after this step, but these issues are resolved analogically.

Comment: Actually, the better practice is to use `target_include_directories(Module1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)/.. )`, *etc.* instead of indiscriminate `include_directories`